# How to get values in a specific column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, rows

I have a datagridview and contain data's there are 5 column each column have many rows. I need to get the data in each cell and put it in the listbox, in horizontal form for example, bread-> 'then the data in each cell' and separated by a comma. please help thanks =)

Comment: It's difficult to determine what you're asking here.  What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

your question is very unclear but this is the basic logic to extract value and add it to a variable from each column cell and each row using nested for loop and add it to a listbox after concatenating it with comma and the word "bread":

```
        Dim MyValue As String = Nothing
        For rowsLoop = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            For ColumnLoop = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                MyValue = DataGridView1.Rows(rowsLoop).Cells(ColumnLoop).Value
                ListBox1.Items.Add("bread" & "," & MyValue.ToString)
            Next
        Next
```